# What are all the situations in which Fortran outputs NaN?

Tags: debugging, fortran, nan

I know that division by zero and square root of negative real number outputs NaN. Are there any other similar problems?

Comment: Probably loads, like arctan, ln, ..

Comment: There are many many functions that can produce NaN's if your system supports IEEE NaN. `SQRT`, `LOG`, `ATAN2`, `ACOS`, `ACOSH`, `FRACTION(X)`, `RRSPACING(X)`, `SET_EXPONENT(X,I)`, `SPACING(X)` are just a few of them. Essentially anything that calls a math function out of its domain. Some more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Operations_generating_NaN)

Comment: Thanks, I looked there... so it can be also caused by overflow? I am trying to find problem in my code, but usual math operations don't seem to be the problem.

Comment: @Andrej: Your compiler might have an option to trap on FP exceptions, printing a backtrace, dumping core, and exiting. That might help pinpoint where it happens.

Comment: With gfortran, for instance, using the flags `-Wall -fcheck=all -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow` helps to find bugs. You can use that, or the similar flags for your compiler, as an extra verification of your code. Integer overflow is not catched from what I read in the man page though.

Comment: You might consider to use `valgrind` (for memory leaks) and any other debuger to step trough your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will refer to the [wikipedia entry on NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Operations_generating_NaN) and to Fortran Standard to try to enumerate them.

> There are three kinds of operations that can return NaN:[5]
>
> - Operations with a NaN as at least one operand.

In Fortran that would include the application of arithmetic and comparisson operators, plus math intrinsic functions.

> - Indeterminate forms:
>
>   - The divisions (±0) / (±0) and (±∞) / (±∞).
>   - The multiplications (±0) × (±∞) and (±∞) × (±0).
>   - The additions (+∞) + (−∞), (−∞) + (+∞) and equivalent subtractions (+∞) − (+∞) and (−∞) − (−∞).
>   - The standard has alternative functions for powers:
>
>     - The standard pow function and the integer exponent pown function define 0⁰, 1∞, and ∞⁰ as 1.
>     - The powr function defines all three indeterminate forms as invalid operations and so returns NaN.

So, all arithmetic operators are included (and also atomic operation functions) . All this was pretty obvious, the fun is next:

> - Real operations with complex results, for example:
>
>   - The square root of a negative number.
>   - The logarithm of a negative number.
>   - The inverse sine or cosine of a number that is less than −1 or greater than 1.

That would mean (as said by @kvantour in the comments) any intrinsic function called out of its domain: `SQRT`, `LOG`, `ATAN`, `ATAN2`, `ACOS`, `ACOSH`, `ASIN`, `ASINH`, `FRACTION`, `RRSPACING`, `SET_EXPONENT`, `SPACING`